# how to make a relationship between tables in Java Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a request SQL and can't implement in Java spring`

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
    mo.MName AS 'Boss',
        tdg.DName AS 'Name group',
        it.IName AS 'Name item',
        tpis.mDesc AS 'Item ',
        CASE
        WHEN evo.mObjID IS NULL THEN 'Not event item'
        ELSE 'Event item'
        END AS 'Event'
        FROM
        DT_Monster AS mo
        INNER JOIN DT_MonsterDrop AS md ON mo.MID = md.MID
        INNER JOIN DT_DropGroup AS dg ON md.DGroup = dg.DGroup
        INNER JOIN TP_DropGroup AS tdg ON md.DGroup = tdg.DGroup
        INNER JOIN DT_DropItem AS di ON dg.DDrop = di.DDrop
        INNER JOIN TP_ItemStatus AS tpis ON di.DStatus = tpis.mStatus
        INNER JOIN DT_Item AS it ON di.DItem = it.IID
        LEFT JOIN TblEventObj AS evo ON it.IID = evo.mObjID
        WHERE
        mo.MID = 84
        and di.DIsEvent = 0
```

```
@Table(name = "DT_Monster")
public class Monster {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "MID", nullable = false)
    private int MID;

    @Column(name = "MName", columnDefinition = "varchar", length = 40)
    private String MName;

    @Column(name = "mLevel")
    private int mLevel;

    @Column(name = "MClass")
    private int MClass;

    @Column(name = "MExp")
    private int MExp;

    @Column(name = "MHIT", columnDefinition = "smallint")
    private short MHIT;

    @Column(name = "MMinD", columnDefinition = "smallint")
    private short MMinD;

    @Column(name = "MMaxD", columnDefinition = "smallint")
    private short MMaxD;

    @Column(name = "MAttackRateOrg", columnDefinition = "smallint")
    private short MAttackRateOrg;

    @Column(name = "MMoveRateOrg", columnDefinition = "smallint")
    private short MMoveRateOrg;

    @Column(name = "MAttackRateNew", columnDefinition = "smallint")
    private short MAttackRateNew;

    @Column(name = "MMoveRateNew", columnDefinition = "smallint")
    private short MMoveRateNew;

    @Column(name = "MHP", columnDefinition = "smallint")
    private short MHP;

    @Column(name = "MMP", columnDefinition = "smallint")
    private short MMP;

    @Column(name = "MMoveRange", columnDefinition = "smallint", nullable = false)
    private short MMoveRange;

    @Column(name = "MGbjType", columnDefinition = "smallint", nullable = false)
    private short MGbjType;

    @Column(name = "MRaceType", columnDefinition = "smallint")
    private short MRaceType;

    @Column(name = "MAiType", columnDefinition = "smallint", nullable = false)
    private short MAiType;

    @Column(name = "MCastingDelay", columnDefinition = "smallint", nullable = false)
    private short MCastingDelay;

    @Column(name = "MChaotic", columnDefinition = "smallint", nullable = false)
    private short MChaotic;

    @Column(name = "MSameRace1", nullable = false)
    private int MSameRace1;

    @Column(name = "MSameRace2", nullable = false)
    private int MSameRace2;

    @Column(name = "MSameRace3", nullable = false)
    private int MSameRace3;

    @Column(name = "MSameRace4", nullable = false)
    private int MSameRace4;

    @Column(name = "mSightRange", nullable = false)
    private int mSightRange;

    @Column(name = "mAttackRange", nullable = false)
    private int mAttackRange;

    @Column(name = "mSkillRange", nullable = false)
    private int mSkillRange;

    @Column(name = "mBodySize", nullable = false)
    private int mBodySize;

    @Column(name = "mDetectTransF", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "smallint")
    private short mDetectTransF;

    @Column(name = "mDetectTransP", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "smallint")
    private short mDetectTransP;

    @Column(name = "mDetectChao", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "smallint")
    private short mDetectChao;

    @Column(name = "mAiEx")
    private int mAiEx;

    @Column(name = "mScale", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "float", length = 53)
    private double mScale;

    @Column(name = "mIsResistTransF", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "bit")
    private boolean mIsResistTransF;

    @Column(name = "mIsEvent", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "bit")
    private boolean mIsEvent;

    @Column(name = "mIsTest", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "bit")
    private boolean mIsTest;

    @Column(name = "mHPNew", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "smallint")
    private short mHPNew;

    @Column(name = "mMPNew", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "smallint")
    private short mMPNew;

    @Column(name = "mBuyMerchanID", nullable = false)
    private int mBuyMerchanID;

    @Column(name = "mSellMerchanID", nullable = false)
    private int mSellMerchanID;

    @Column(name = "mChargeMerchanID", nullable = false)
    private int mChargeMerchanID;

    @Column(name = "mTransformWeight", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "smallint")
    private short mTransformWeight;

    @Column(name = "mNationOp", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "bigint")
    private long mNationOp;

    @Column(name = "mHPRegen", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "smallint")
    private short mHPRegen;

    @Column(name = "mMPRegen", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "smallint")
    private short mMPRegen;

    @Column(name = "IContentsLv", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "tinyint")
    private byte IContentsLv;

    @Column(name = "mIsEventTest", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "bit")
    private boolean mIsEventTest;

    @Column(name = "mIsShowHp", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "bit")
    private boolean mIsShowHp;

    @Column(name = "mSupportType", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "timyint")
    private byte mSupportType;

    @Column(name = "mVolitionOfHonor", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "smallint")
    private short mVolitionOfHonor;

    @Column(name = "mWMapIconType", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "smallint")
    private short mWMapIconType;

    @Column(name = "mIsAmpliableTermOfValidity", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "bit")
    private boolean mIsAmpliableTermOfValidity;

    @Column(name = "mAttackType", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "tinyint")
    private byte mAttackType;

    @Column(name = "mTransType", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "tinyint")
    private byte mTransType;

    @Column(name = "mDPV", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "smallint")
    private short mDPV;

    @Column(name = "mMPV", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "smallint")
    private short mMPV;

    @Column(name = "mRPV", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "smallint")
    private short mRPV;

    @Column(name = "mDDV", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "smallint")
    private short mDDV;

    @Column(name = "mMDV", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "smallint")
    private short mMDV;

    @Column(name = "mRDV", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "smallint")
    private short mRDV;

    @Column(name = "mSubDDWhenCritical", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "smallint")
    private short mSubDDWhenCritical;

    @Column(name = "mEnemySubCriticalHit", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "smallint")
    private short mEnemySubCriticalHit;

    @Column(name = "mEventQuest", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "tinyint")
    private byte mEventQuest;

    @Column(name = "mEScale", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "float", length = 53)
    private double mEScale;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "monster", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<MonsterDrop> monsterDrops = new ArrayList<>();

    public Monster() {}

}
```

```
@Table(name = "DT_MonsterDrop")
public class MonsterDrop {

    @Id
    private int MID;

    @Column(name = "DGroup")
    private int DGroup;

    @Column(name = "DPercent", columnDefinition = "tinyint")
    private byte DPercent;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Monster monster;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DGroup", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private DropGroup dropGroup;

    public MonsterDrop(){}


}
```

```
@Table(name = "DT_DropGroup")
public class DropGroup {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "DGroup")
    private int DGroup;

    @Column(name = "DDrop")
    private int DDrop;

    @Column(name = "DPercent", columnDefinition = "real")
    private float DPercent;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "dropGroup", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<MonsterDrop> monsterDrops = new ArrayList<>();

    public DropGroup() {}


}
```

> CODE ERROR org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table DT_MonsterDrop add constraint FKmsdbtbsin4to948knbnc44on8 foreign key (DGroup) references DT_DropGroup" via JDBC Statement

Problem in

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Monster monster;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DGroup", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private DropGroup dropGroup;
```

if you remove the @JoinColumn the problem is not

similar problem in
@JoinColumn(name = "MID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
and
@JoinColumn(name = "DGroup", insertable=false, updatable=false)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Foreign key 'FKmsdbtbsin4to948knbnc44on8' has implicit reference to object 'DT_DropGroup' which does not have a primary key defined on it.

Comment: I was given a table in which there are no keys, can I do it without adding keys?